# Can't Connect IPhone to Xcode 5.1?

Tags: iphone, xcode5.1

I have registered from Apple.com. Previously I have uploaded app also to apple.itunensconnect.com. I just upgrade my mac os & Xcode and trying to connect iPhone. iPhone is connected to system but in Xcode not showing device name

i am new to Xcode, I have small IPhone Mobile App, I am trying to connect my IPhone to Xcode 5.1 but unable to detect.

In my mac system showing/connecting IPhone. In Xcode not showing?

can any one tell me how to connect iPhone to Xcode 5.1?

thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you registered to be a paid Apple developer??? And created a provisioning profile with this device on it?? Providing a more detailed answer just gathering information

Comment: What is your iphone ios version ?

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya, iPhone version is 6.2.

Comment: is your deployment target maybe on iOS 7.0 ? in that case Xcode will not show your phone as possible device to run on. does your device show up in the xcode organizer with a green light? if not done already, press "use for development".

Comment: @JeanLuc, may be I vl back after upgrade & checking from Xcode. thank you

Comment: what? I don't get you. And iPhone Version 6.2 does not exist.

Comment: @JeanLuc, iPhone IOS SDK Version 6.1.6.

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that you haven't registered as a paid Apple developer on the [Apple Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/register/index.action).

When developing apps for iOS you are required to register with Apple as an Apple developer. There are 3 options a **Free** Apple developer Account which doesn't really allow you to do much at all, you can't test on devices, you can't submit to the App Store. There is also the 2 paid options.

Option 1: Is the first paid option for $99 a year which will allow you to create a provisioning profile and submit to the app store Option 1 can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/standard/)

Option 2: Is for more bigger organizations but it cost $299 and can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/enterprise/)

All the options can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/ios/)

Once you are a fully paid up Apple developer you will need to create a [provisioning profile](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html) which has your device on it. Once this is all complete you should be able to developer apps for your device.

If you are a paid up developer and have the correct provisioning profile please can you update your question and I will amend my answer.

Comment: I have registered from Apple.com. Previously I have uploaded app also to apple.itunensconnect.com. I just upgrade my mac os & Xcode and trying to connect iPhone. iPhone is connected to system but in Xcode not showing device name.

Comment: See that is a piece of information that we need to know to help you out. Please can you update your question to include this new information.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because

1. The deployment target is higher than your iPhone version
2. The supported device is set to iPad